# How to select session M-a in tmux using keyboard

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

In [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) I have multiple sessions running.  To switch sessions, I hit my tmux escape sequence and then the `s` key.  The session list appears:

[image: tmux session list]

Now I can hit the key `4`, for example, if I want to go to session `blacklist`.

I want to go to session `g-orchestrator`.  *Without using the arrow keys*, what key combination can I hit to enter that session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

M-a means "Meta-a", which is usually Alt-a in most terminal programs (in Apple's Terminal.app you must enable the app preference "Use option as Meta key" before this will work). So, in this case, the key combination Alt-a will take you to that session directly. Additional sessions will be reachable via Alt-b, Alt-c, Alt-d, etc.

Comment: Works like a charm.  I found the setting under Profiles > Keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [iTerm2](https://iterm2.com/).

#### What did not work for me on iTerm2

- Using the "Meta" setting for the left or right option key.

#### What worked for me on iTerm2

- Holding down the **escape** key and hitting "a".  Although weirdly enough it doesn't work consistently.  Sometimes I have to release the escape key and do it again a second time.
- Using the "Esc+" setting for the left or right option key.  Then for example I hold down the **option** key and hit "a".  This seems to be working fairly reliable.  The setting is under Profiles > Keys > Left Option key / Right Option key, and I include a picture below:

[image]

Comment: "Esc-a" and "Meta-a" aren't quite identical, as you've noticed. This is due to the fact that the Option key is purely a modifier, whereas the Escape key performs double duties as both the first character in an escape sequence, plus a standalone character with its own meaning, resulting in ambiguities for anything in the TTY pipeline that needs to respond to these sequences.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: How do I make the option/alt key act like Meta or send escape codes?
> A: Go to Preferences > Profiles tab. Select your profile on the left, and then open the Keyboard tab. At the bottom is a set of buttons that lets you select the behavior of the Option key. For most users, Esc+ will be the best choice.

From https://iterm2.com/faq.html

Esc+ is the best choice for most users. I tried `Meta` and `Normal`. Meta worked if not in Tmux, but didn't work in Tmux.